# Text won't wrap using JavaScript (absolute position and wordwrap)

Tags: javascript, html, position, absolute

I have my page split into columns (div), like that:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="left" style="float:left; width:15%;">
    some text...
</div>

<div id="mid" style="float:left; width:70%;">
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I need the text and long words to wrap in the left column. At first I was using the CSS property:

```
    word-wrap: break-word;
```

and it works just fine

Now, my problem is that I'm giving the text an absolute position using JavaScript, and the whole text doesn't wrap anymore at all (it's not even a long words-related problem).
Here is what I have among my JavaScript lines:

```
document.getElementById("lefttext").style.position = "absolute";
document.getElementById("lefttext").style.top = 500 + "px";
```

Also tried to add that, but it doesn't help:

```
document.getElementById("lefttext").style.wordWrap="break-word";
```

Comment: Can you setup a working jsfiddle to illustrate the problem? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Also, I assume `lefttext` is `left` in your HTML?